# Conversion of list(fetched from mysql database) to dataframe takes lot of time

Tags: mysql, r, performance, dataframe

I am trying to fetch a data frame from the mysql database.

```
my_db=src_mysql(dbname='****',
                host='****'
                ,port=****,user='****',password='****')
```

From this database(which shows as list of 2 in global environment) I want to extract a table.

```
w = src_tbls(my_db)[1]
```

But the above command return me a list. I actually needed  dataframe. Now to convert this list to dataframe is taking a lot of time.

Can anyone suggest me a way to directly extract a dataframe from the database and reduce the total execution time of code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with `src_mysql()`, but you might try the RODBC package.

This should give you a dataframe of your table and it might be faster given that your SQL statement isn't slow:

```
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("your dsn as character string", 
                       uid="****", # Username         
                       pwd="****",     
                       believeNRows=FALSE)
w <- sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE")
```